# Joining to a Resource Model that doesn't have a Select?

Tags: model, collection, reports

So I have this resource model that I pulled from some admin code on the dashboard.  It works, but I can't seem to join to it. Doing `->getSelect()->__toString();` shows nothing? So is this not a normal collection?  Why does it not work like other collections?

My guess that in order to accomplish what I want to accomplish is that I am going to have to extend the collection model, but I just wanted to see if I can get more of an idea of what is going on here.

```
$storeId = $this->helper('core')->getStoreId();
$collection = Mage::getResourceModel('sales/report_bestsellers_collection')
    ->setModel('catalog/product')
    ->addStoreFilter($storeId);

$collection->getSelect()->join(
        array('category_product' => 'catalog_category_product'),
        'main_table.product_id = category_product.product_id', 
        array('category_product.*')
    )->where('category_product.category_id = ?', '3')
     ->order('main_table.qty_ordered DESC')
     ->limit($limit);
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The reporting collections work a bit differently that the  `Mage_Core_Model_Abstract`/CRUD collections.  The CRUD collections will have a SQL query assigned immediately at instantiation. The reporting collection, however, initializes its SQL statement during its load operation.  You can see this in the `load` method down in the abstract base class for all reporting collections.

```
#File: app/code/core/Mage/Reports/Model/Resource/Report/Collection/Abstract.php
public function load($printQuery = false, $logQuery = false)
{
    if ($this->isLoaded()) {
        return $this;
    }
    $this->_initSelect();
    if ($this->_applyFilters) {
        $this->_applyDateRangeFilter();
        $this->_applyStoresFilter();
        $this->_applyCustomFilter();
    }
    return parent::load($printQuery, $logQuery);
}
```

There's no select until `_initSelect` is called.

The general approach you'll want to take here is

1. Create a new resource model class which extends the `Mage_Reports_Model_Resource_Report_Collection_Abstract` class
2. Define a  `_applyCustomFilter` method in your class

and then use your new resource model.  Your `_applyCustomFilter` method would look something like this.

```
protected function _applyCustomFilter()
{
    $return = parent::_applyCustomFilter();
    //manipulate the select all you want here (`$this->getSelect()`)
    return $return;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you're trying to load a list of "best selling" products (and filtered by a given category), I've done it in the past using the product collection from the Reports module.

Give this a shot:

```
$category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load(3);
$report = Mage::getResourceModel('reports/product_collection')
        ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
        ->addOrderedQty()
        ->setOrder('ordered_qty', 'desc')
        ->addCategoryFilter($category);
```

Comment: I wanted to avoid this method because I thought it would be too heavy, and preferred the already aggregated table over it thaet is populated by a cron job.   I mean is that query above going to be heavy if I put a limit 30 on it?  I guess it could be further investigated by me, but for now I'm going to stick with the bestsellers aggregate table due to lack of time to investigate